# Dockerized Nestjs with Redis and getting NOAUTH authentication required error

Tags: docker, redis, nestjs

After dockized `nestjs` and `redis` to use `cache manager` with this configuration:

```
services:
  my_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/app/Dockerfile
      target: development
    command: npm run start:dev my_app
    env_file:
      - src/.env
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - default
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
    ports:
      - '80:3000'

  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
    command: /bin/sh -c "redis-server --requirepass $$REDIS_PASSWORD"
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - ./redis/data:/data
```

`.env`:

```
REDIS_PASSWORD=password
REDIS_URI=redis://:${REDIS_PASSWORD}@redis:6379?authSource=0
# ---> REDIS_URI=redis://public:${REDIS_PASSWORD}@redis:6379?authSource=0
```

setting up `AppModule`:

```js
BullModule.forRoot(
    {
        redis: {
            host: 'redis',
            port: 6379
        }
    }
),
```

I get this error:

```
return new ReplyError(string)
       ^
ReplyError: NOAUTH Authentication required.
```

how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a password to `BullModule` solved my issue:

```js
BullModule.forRoot(
    {
        redis: {
            host: 'redis',
            port: 6379,
            password: `${process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD}`, // Added this line
        }
    }
),
```